# To play Twilio ivr and then redirect it to get response

Tags: codeigniter, twilio

Trying to redirect to my file when ivr is been played.It is redirecting also I am receiving the response, but it plays error as : **there is application error.** Following is my code:

```
<Response>
<?php if ($_REQUEST['Digits'] == '1') { ?> 
 <Say>The call failed</Say>
 <Pause length="5"/>
 <Redirect method="POST">Here i added my redirection url</Redirect>
<?php } elseif ($_REQUEST['Digits'] == '2') { ?>
 <Say>Record your monkey howl after the tone.</Say> 
<?php } ?>
</Response>
```

Not getting why its playing error as : **there is application error.** , as everything working fine.

Comment: Start with simple code to return valid XML then you can add more as you go. For example you could start by just returning `<Response><Say>Hello.</Say></Response>`

Comment: <Response><Say>Hello.</Say></Response> this works well but when I try to redirect it to another url to get store the response it, gives an there is application error.Everything works well like message(<Say>Hello</Say>) and also store response but at last it says an ' there is application error'.I have used <redirect></redirect> tag to redirect its not working.